# .NET DateTime displayed in FormView

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, formview

I have a WCF service that provides a data object where one attribute is DateTime created by calling `new DateTime(10,1,1995)`

Anyhow when this data object is linked to FormView as data source i get a DateTime format error. I tried to change the FormView in source but i dont know how to access the object.

```
<ItemTemplate>
    ExtensionData:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="ExtensionDataDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="ExtensionData" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    Authors:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="AuthorsDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="Authors" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    Description:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="DescriptionDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="Description" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    PubDate:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="PubDateDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="PubDate" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    PubID:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="PubIDDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="PubID" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    Publisher:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="PublisherDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="Publisher" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />
    Title:
    <asp:DynamicControl ID="TitleDynamicControl" runat="server" DataField="Title" Mode="ReadOnly" />
    <br />

</ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: It's possible that the problem is in the data object. Perhaps you could post that, or at least tell us a little about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got the order of the parameters in the `DateTime` constructor backwards.

It should be:

```
new DateTime( 1995, 1, 10 ) // year, month, day
```

Comment: Thatnks dont know how i didnt notice that when i was looking up DateTime on msdn page. Thanks a lot mate.